# Spring Cloud Netflix /refresh deregisters service

Tags: spring, cloud, config, netflix, netflix-eureka

I have service "usermanagement" on port 10351 (localhost:10351 ... testing ) running under Spring Cloud Eureka Server (port 8761)
Application gets registered fine and I can see it on Eureka dashboard

When I issue POST to refresh that application beans, application gets de-registered from Eureka Server and never registers back.

POST http://localhost:10351/refresh

How do I make application register back after /refresh ?

Here is log from after I issue POST:

```
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] --- Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet --- FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet --- FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 40 ms 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication --- Starting application on TUSFL000LKVT4TN with PID 19212 (C:\Users\nickb\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar started by v227873 in C:\uiam\workspace\uiam.git2\commonservices\usermanagement-cloud) 
o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext --- Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@536f88ca: startup date [Wed Aug 26 11:03:50 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor --- JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring 
o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker --- Bean 'encrypt.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 
o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker --- Bean 'encryptionBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4525514] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 
o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor --- Starting beans in phase 0 
o.s.c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration --- Registering application usermanagement with eureka with status UP 
o.s.c.n.c.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration --- Locating configserver via discovery 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication --- Started application in 0.305 seconds (JVM running for 124.036) 
o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration --- Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='link_to_mycompany_git/scm/uiam/service-config-store.git/usermanagement.yml#development'], MapPropertySource [name='link_to_mycompany_git/scm/uiam/service-config-store.git/usermanagement.yml']]] 
o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext --- Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2be8f1c7: startup date [Wed Aug 26 11:03:52 EDT 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@536f88ca 
o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor --- JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring 
o.s.c.n.c.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration --- Locating configserver via discovery 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication --- Started application in 1.543 seconds (JVM running for 125.24) 
o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext --- Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2be8f1c7: startup date [Wed Aug 26 11:03:52 EDT 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@536f88ca 
o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext --- Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@536f88ca: startup date [Wed Aug 26 11:03:50 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor --- Stopping beans in phase 0 
o.s.c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration --- Unregistering application usermanagement with eureka with status DOWN 
o.s.c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration --- Closing DiscoveryClient.jerseyClient 
o.s.c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration --- Removing application usermanagement from eureka 
c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient --- DiscoveryClient_USERMANAGEMENT/TUSFL000LKVT4TN:usermanagement:10351:0579e19a2d4e3e88d60686eb208d180a - deregister  status: 200
```

See last line ?
DiscoveryClient --- DiscoveryClient_USERMANAGEMENT/TUSFL000LKVT4TN:usermanagement:10351:0579e19a2d4e3e88d60686eb208d180a - deregister  status: 200

After that - nothing

I'm using this version of Spring cloud

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

If it matters, I do not have application.yml in my app itself, but I fetch it from our company's GIT. It contains DB dataSource params

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the exact same problem. If I switch to spring-cloud-starter-parent 1.0.2.RELEASE the problem goes away. Maybe it's a bug?